# How to create a list from tuples with sub-tuples?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples, python-itertools

I have two lists `a` and `b`. Then I create all combinations taking all two-length combinations of `a` plus one each of `b`:

```
import itertools as it

a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [5,6]

for i in it.product(it.combinations(a, 2), b):
    print (i)

# output:
  ((1, 2), 5)
  ((1, 2), 6)
  ((1, 3), 5)
  ...

# expected output:
  [1, 2, 5]
  [1, 2, 6]
  [1, 3, 5]
  ...
```

How can the tuples be transformed at the stage of the loop operation into lists?

Comment: If the number of items in the product is fixed, like here, I do not see much benefit to use it over nested `for` loops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following comprehensions will work:

```
>>> [[*x, y] for x, y in it.product(it.combinations(a, 2), b)]  # Py3
>>> [list(x) + [y] for x, y in it.product(it.combinations(a, 2), b)]  # all Py versions
[[1, 2, 5],
 [1, 2, 6],
 [1, 3, 5],
 [1, 3, 6],
 [1, 4, 5],
 [1, 4, 6],
 [2, 3, 5],
 [2, 3, 6],
 [2, 4, 5],
 [2, 4, 6],
 [3, 4, 5],
 [3, 4, 6]]
```

Comment: "at the stage of the loop operation" could mean that the for-loop should be retained, but `for i` should be replaced with `for x,y` and `print(i)` should be replaced with `print([*x,y])`.

Comment: @Acccumulation Possibly, but I think one can take it from here.

Comment: it was the smallest problem, I've already transformed my code for my purposes :)

Answer (score 1):

Simplified approach:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [5,6]
l = len(a)
print(sorted([a[i], a[i_n], j] for i in range(l) for j in b
             for i_n in range(i+1, l) if i < l-1))
```

The output:

```
[[1, 2, 5], [1, 2, 6], [1, 3, 5], [1, 3, 6], [1, 4, 5], [1, 4, 6], [2, 3, 5], [2, 3, 6], [2, 4, 5], [2, 4, 6], [3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 6]]
```